# glsl infinity constant

Tags: glsl, infinity

Does GLSL have any pre-defined constants for +/-infinity or NaN? I'm doing this as a workaround but I wonder if there is a cleaner way:

```
// GLSL FRAGMENT SHADER
#version 410

<snip>

const float infinity = 1. / 0.;

void main ()
{
    <snip>
}
```

I am aware of the `isinf` function but I need to assign infinity to a variable so that does not help me.

Comment: Using infinity saves a lot of logic in my code: `<snip> float t0 = (d >= 0.) ? t : infinity; <snip> float t1 = (d >= 0.) ? t : infinity; t = min (t0, t1); <snip>`

Comment: I believe choosing a large enough value (based on your application) should easily do the trick. Say for example `1e20`

Comment: Using infinity seems to work fine, I was just wondering if there was a pre-defined constant for it. While I'm at it, are there constants for other things like FLT_MAX FLT_EPSILON etc the way there are in C?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like [Nicol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10436239/369009) mentioned, there are no pre-defined constants.

However, from OpenGL 4.1 on, your solution is at least guaranteed to work and correctly generate an infinite value.

See for example in [glsl 4.4](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf):

> **4.7.1 Range and Precision**
>
> ...
>
> However, **dividing a non-zero by 0 results in the
> appropriately signed IEEE Inf**: If both positive and negative zeros are implemented, the correctly signed
> Inf will be generated, otherwise positive Inf is generated.

Be careful when you use an older version of OpenGL though:

For example in [glsl 4.0](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.00.9.clean.pdf) it says:

> **4.1.4 Floats**
>
> ...
>
> Similarly, treatment of conditions such as **divide by 0 may lead to an unspecified result**, but in no case should such a condition lead to the interruption or termination of processing.

Answer (score 6):

There are no pre-defined constants for it, but there is the `isinf` function to test if something is infinity.

> While I'm at it, are there constants for other things like FLT_MAX FLT_EPSILON etc the way there are in C?

No, there are not.

Answer (score 6):

This might work?

```
const float pos_infinity = uintBitsToFloat(0x7F800000);
const float neg_infinity = uintBitsToFloat(0xFF800000);
```

"If the encoding of a floating point infinity is passed in parameter x, the resulting floating-point value is the corresponding (positive or negative) floating point infinity"